# Can't use AutoLayout Constraints on UNNotificationContentExtension

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios10, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to add a custom notification in iOS 10 that utilizes the force press rich notifications.  I want to programmatically add a view to the center of the view controller that inherits from UNNotificationContentExtension, but all I get is a white screen. The content is added when I give it a frame like this:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import UserNotificationsUI

class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myView = UIView()
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
    }

    func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {

    }

}
```

Which looks like this:
[image]
But when I try using AutoLayout programmatically (with the PureLayout wrapper) using this code:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import UserNotificationsUI

class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myView = UIView()
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(myView)

        myView.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .top)
        myView.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .left)
        myView.autoMatch(.width, to: .width, of: self.view)
        myView.autoMatch(.height, to: .height, of: self.view)
    }

    func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {

    }

}
```

The result is this: [image]

What would cause AutoLayout to not work in this view controller?  I've tested it with the interface builder as well, so I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a view programmatically, you have to remember to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false or auto layout won't behave like you expect.

Comment: That's definitely something I missed, but it still didn't fix the issue.  If I set the background color of self.view to black, the background does what I expect.  As soon as I add one constraint to the myView I get a blank screen.